# Distribution of $Y=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1}}^{n}{\dfrac{1}{x_{i}}}$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inequality, random-variables

I consider n points distributed uniformly in [0, 1], and I form a graph in which each vertex is linked to another vertex if the distance between them is smaller than $r=\dfrac{K}{n}$, where K is fixed.

So, $x_{i}$ represents the sum of all nodes that are linked to the node $i$ and $ x_{i} \sim Poisson (K)$.

We assume that the graph is connected, then each node is at least linked to 1 another node which means that $x_{i}$ will never take the value 0. Also, the variables $x_{i}$ for $i \in \lbrace1..n\rbrace$ are not independent.

There exists a theorem in the book of 'Penrose' who shows that  $X=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1}}^{n}{x_{i}}$ is distributed as(because of the dependence of $x{i}$, it was not very clear for me until I found the theorem):
$$ X \sim Poisson (nK)$$

Now, the problem is to find the distribution of what follows:

$$Y=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1}}^{n}{\dfrac{1}{x_{i}}}?$$

The big problem in this work is the dependance between $x_{i}$.

Thank you.

Comment: In the simplest case, $x_i\sim i.i.d. \mathrm{Poisson}(K)$, the variable $Y$ can be undefined because $x_i$ has a chance to be $0$. Please give more background to motivate this problem.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe One could say that $Y$ takes values in the extended real numbers, and define $Y=+\infty$ whenever one of the $x_{i}=0,$ but I'm not sure this is the OP's intent.

Comment: if n is sufficiently large, Y will be normal distribution by Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I don't think this has to be true; it's not even clear that the individual terms will have finite expectation, as discussed by the previous commenters.

Comment: If it possible to compute the expectation value E[Y]

Comment: would the expectation value E[Y] be $\sum_i^n 1/nK$

Comment: that'd be 1/K $\sum_i^n 1/n$

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will update the question and give more details.

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Why would it be that?

Comment: because by definition the expectation value of the nth term is 1/nK since the Poisson distribution has mean nK?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 You do realize that we do not have $\mathbb{E}[1/X] = 1/\mathbb{E}[X]$ in general, right?

Comment: of course ... you're really smart

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: So... $X_i$ is Poisson *conditioned on being at least $1$*? That's going to get messy.